# How to align text in angularjs material design

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-material

I am using angular material design. This is my code for a floating label for input in HTML.

```
<h5>LOGIN</h5>
<md-input-container class="md-block">
    <label>Mobile Number</label>

    <input readonly required="" name="mobileNumber" ng-model="mobile" minlength="10" maxlength="10" ng-pattern="/^[0-9]{10}$/">


    <div ng-messages="projectForm.mobileNumber.$error" role="alert">
      <div ng-message-exp="['required', 'minlength', 'maxlength', 'pattern']">
            Please enter 10 digit mobile number.
      </div>
    </div>
    <md-button ui-sref="ConfirmAccount" class="md-primary" >Change Number?</md-button>

</md-input-container>
```

[image]

I want change number? to be displayed on right end of input text i.e. 55555555.

Can anyone help me on this?

Answer (score -1):

```
<input readonly required="" name="mobileNumber" ng-model="mobile" minlength="10" maxlength="10" ng-pattern="/^[0-9]{10}$/">
<md-button ui-sref="ConfirmAccount" class="md-primary" >Change Number?</md-button>
```

As div is a block element, I believe Change Number? is coming in new line. Now, we have moved it above the div. So, it should be fine.

Comment: Thanks for your response. I tried this. But still not working.

Comment: @DeveshAgrawal See this fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/nagasandeepbondili/t5991vpf/2/

Answer (score -3):

Try with `style="text-align:right"`:

Example

```
<input ng-model="vm.invline.price" type="text" readonly style="text-align:right">
```

real image:
[image]